Is my furnace pilot flame too large due to flow or pressure?
I have a old Rheem, model RGAA-125A, furnace that was converted from natural gas to propane long ago when installed.
We ran out of propane gas at the end of the winter, so the pilot went out. The propane tank was recently refilled. Large pig tank filled to 80%. Now the pilot can not be lit. The gas control valve is a Unitrol 7000BER.
The pilot has good flow but maybe too much as a lighter flame to the pilot only has a flame up past the pilot like a flame thrower. This system has a regulator at the propane tank and a secondary regulator by the house before the pipe goes into the house. I have adjusted up and down the pilot flow control but either the flame is too high (only with a lighter flame at the pilot) or no gas flow at all. I also purchased a new propane pilot assembly. both have the same issue.
Is this a symptom of high flow or high pressure? I have not checked gas pressure as of yet.









The range of adjustment for the pilot should be multiple screw turns. IOW, it should be many turns from too high to nothing. Perhaps what you are turning is not actually the screw to adjust the pilot.

is the gas in the pipes full sctregth or did it get dlluted?

Thank you for all of the replies so far. I am adjusting the flow at the correct flow adjustment, flow control screw is under the screw cap next to the pilot tube. but the adjustment is from complete chock off to small flam thrower to high flam thrower. Now maybe the flow control spring is bad. Just not sure if the issue is high flow or high pressure.

Just speculating on what your problem could be... Nat gas uses a larger size than LP for the same BTU. I suppose it is possible that since the valve is designed for natural gas, the adjustment range does not match what you need for LP. Or, could there be a separate orifice for the pilot that was never changed? Or, is it possible that when the furnace was "converted" in the past, it was done by adjusting the regulator for lower than normal pressure instead of changing the orifices. Then, when refilling your tank, the tech checked and adjusted the regulator back to the normal / correct pressure?

Or, is it possible that the new pilot assembly is for natural gas instead of propane? Which would explain why it cannot be adjusted low enough.

@user322174 - You are definitely getting too much gas. That could be the orifice too large or the pressure too high (or both). Perhaps someone adjusted the regulator (in the past) trying to get more gas out of the tank when it was very low or empty. I am not familiar with LP systems, but it should not be difficult to find out what gas pressure should be. I am also not qualified to advise correct method or equipment to test the pressure. Measuring gas pressure is usually straightforward, maybe something your gas supplier could do for you.
